# Dynamodb boto Table.scan with AND condition

Tags: boto

I want to add AND kind of filter in Table.scan,

For example:

```
scanneditems = logTable.scan(unitid__eq='dev1',time__gte=condition1 and time__lt=condition2)
```

I need items with time greater than condition1 but less than condition2, how do I add AND type of condition here?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to place two conditions on the same AttributeName, FilterExpression's are the way to go.  Here is a snippet a code from boto 2.34 demonstrating your filter above.

```
# db in this case represents the boto.dynamodb2.layer1.DynamoDBConnection object
db.scan(<Your Table>, filter_expression="unitid = :a AND time > :b AND time < :c",
        expression_attribute_values={":a" : {"S": "dev1"}, ":b": <condition1>, ":c": <condition2>})
```

Let me know if you need anything else, thanks!

Comment: Hi Raymond,Thank you for your help. I am receiving "<boto.dynamodb2.table.Table object at 0x1099ef450> is not JSON serializable" Error while trying to do scan as you mentioned.

Comment: Oh, I think I was vague when I said <Your Table>, but that should be your TableName as a string (i.e. "LogTable").  Sorry about that!

Comment: Hey Raymond, Yes I replaced it with correct name. And that was the error I was getting after that. "<boto.dynamodb2.table.Table object at 0x1099ef450> is not JSON serializable"